# Pause song on next click, Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 5 div boxes that play a certain track on click (using data attributes), however, I can't seem to figure out how to pause the previous track on next click. The audio plays on top of each other.

Javascript:

```
var audio = ['song-1.mp3','song-2.mp3','song-3.mp3','song-4.mp3','song-
5.mp3'];

var music = document.querySelector('#container');

music.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
 if(evt.target.tagName === "DIV"){

 var index = evt.target.getAttribute('data-index');

 var sound = new Audio(audio[index]);
 sound.play();

 audio.forEach(function(x){
  if(x !== sound){
   sound.pause();
  }
 })

}

});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
 <body>

  <section id="container">
    <div data-index="0"><p>40's</p></div>
    <div data-index="1"><p>50's</p></div>
    <div data-index="2"><p>60's</p></div>
    <div data-index="3"><p>70's</p></div>
    <div data-index="4"><p>80's</p></div>
    <div data-index="5"><p>90's</p></div>
    <div data-index="6"><p>2000's</p></div>
    <div data-index="7"><p>2010's</p></div>
  </section>


 <script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sound` will always refers to the most recently clicked sound, never to the one that was playing before. The easiest solution is probably to keep a variable `playing` that tracks the audio object that is currently playing. That way when a new sound is played, you have a reference to the old one that you can pause. That could look something like this

```
var audio = ['song-1.mp3','song-2.mp3','song-3.mp3','song-4.mp3','song-
5.mp3'];

var music = document.querySelector('#container');

var playing = undefined;

music.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
  if(evt.target.tagName === "DIV"){

    var index = evt.target.getAttribute('data-index');

    var sound = new Audio(audio[index]);
    if (playing) playing.pause();
    sound.play();
    playing = sound;
  }
});
```

Another option is for you to just keep an array of audio objects and track the index of the currently playing audio. That could look like this. This may be preferable because it will keep the place of paused songs.

```
var audioNames = ['song-1.mp3','song-2.mp3','song-3.mp3','song-4.mp3','song-
5.mp3'];
var audio = [];
for (var a in audioNames) {
    audio.push(new Audio(a));
}

var music = document.querySelector('#container');

var playingIndex = undefined;

music.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
  if(evt.target.tagName === "DIV"){

    var index = evt.target.getAttribute('data-index');

    var sound = audio[index];
    if (playing) audio[playingIndex].pause();
    sound.play();
    playingIndex = index;
  }
});
```